# How to work with temporary tables in foreachBatch?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

We are building a streaming platform where it is essential to work with SQL's in batches.

```
val query = streamingDataSet.writeStream.option("checkpointLocation", checkPointLocation).foreachBatch { (df, batchId) => {

      df.createOrReplaceTempView("events")

      val df1 = ExecutionContext.getSparkSession.sql("select * from events")

      df1.limit(5).show()
      // More complex processing on dataframes

    }}.trigger(trigger).outputMode(outputMode).start()

query.awaitTermination()
```

Error thrown is :

```
org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQueryException: Table or view not found: events
Caused by: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.analysis.NoSuchTableException: Table or view 'events' not found in database 'default';
```

Streaming source is Kafka with watermarking and without using Spark-SQL we are able to execute dataframe transformations. Spark version is 2.4.0 and Scala is 2.11.7. Trigger is ProcessingTime every 1 minute and OutputMode is Append.

Is there any other approach to facilitate use of spark-sql within foreachBatch ? Would it work with upgraded version of Spark - in which case to version do we upgrade ? 
Kindly help. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** Replace `ExecutionContext.getSparkSession` with `df.sparkSession`.

---

The reason of the `StreamingQueryException` is that the streaming query tries to access the `events` temporary table in a `SparkSession` that knows nothing about it, i.e. `ExecutionContext.getSparkSession`.

The only `SparkSession` that has this `events` temporary table registered is exactly the `SparkSession` the `df` dataframe is created within, i.e. `df.sparkSession`.

Comment: I am also getting the same error but this df.sparkSession is not working for me in pyspark as I am getting 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sparkSession'

Comment: `df.sparkSession` is available for Scala while you seem to be using Python. I'd recommend giving `SparkSession.getActiveSession()` a shot instead.

Answer (score 1):

Please check the code snippet below. Here, I have created two separate DataFrames, *responseDF1* and *responseDF2* from *resultDF* and shown the output in the console. *responseDF2* is created using a temporary table. You can try the same.

```
resultDF.writeStream.foreachBatch {(batchDF: DataFrame, batchId: Long) =>
batchDF.persist()
val responseDF1 = batchDF.selectExpr("ResponseObj.type","ResponseObj.key", "ResponseObj.activity", "ResponseObj.price")
responseDF1.show()
responseDF1.createTempView("responseTbl1")
val responseDF2 = batchDF.sparkSession.sql("select activity, key from responseTbl1")
responseDF2.show()
batchDF.sparkSession.catalog.dropTempView("responseTbl1")
batchDF.unpersist()
()}.start().awaitTermination()
```

[Code Snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f75Wh.jpg)